# How to set up file docker-compose with mysql and tomcat in IDE Intelij?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, tomcat

I am working on a personal project using Jsp / servlet so it needs tomcat to run. I created a compose docker file for mysql and I want to have tomcat inside the file and how to set it up in the IDE instead of downloading it from tomcat.apache.org and setting it up into the Intelij IDE. Can you guys help me? Thank you very much!

```
version: '3'
services:
  db_bookstore:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3210:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=654321
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstore
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have tomcat service in your Docker, right?

```
version: '3'
services:
  db_bookstore:
  ...

  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:9.0.12
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
```

Comment: so then how can I setup tomcat in Intelij?